# Qual a diferença entre QString e QStringLiteral?

Tags: c++, string, qt

Qual a diferença entre os dois? Qual é o melhor de se usar?

Comment: Se possível me passem tutoriais/sites de informação de Qt em português por favor... Para eu me aprofundar nesse framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) é um tipo representa textos na Qt. É o equivalente ao tipo `string` do C++, mas eles não são compatíveis, são armazenados de forma diferente. Quando usa-se a Qt costuma ser mais vantajoso aplicar esse tipo para evitar conversões desnecessárias em várias situações.

```
QString variavel("hello world");
```

O [`QStringLiteral`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QStringLiteral) é só uma macro criada à partir da versão 5 que cria um literal *string* compatível com o tipo `QString`. Antes o que acabava sendo feito é criar um literal `string` padrão e aí uma conversão acabava sendo feita quando passava ele para um método da Qt que espera um `Qstring`. Esta macro evita esta conversão.

```
if (node.hasAttribute(QStringLiteral("http-contents-length")))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Qt/QStringXQLiteral.cpp).

Material em português da Qt é bem complicado, dá uma olha [nesse](http://www.lcm.com.br/site/#livros/detalhesLivro/programacao-em--qt.html), mas não sei se é bom.